# My ListView Won't read items from an ObservableCollection<T> made from ordinary List<T>

Tags: c#, xamarin

Here is my code

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        mytb.Add(dp1);
        mytb.Add(dp2);
        mytb.Add(dp3);
        mytb.Add(dp4);          
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;
       
    }     
    public static List<Departments> mytb { get; set; } = new List<Departments>();   

    public ObservableCollection<Departments> mytb2 { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Departments>(mytb);     

    Departments dp1 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
    Departments dp2 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
    Departments dp3 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
    Departments dp4 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
```

Nathing appears on my ListView when i bind my ListView ItemSource to `mytb2` ,but when i use this code

```
     public MainPage()
    {
        mytb.Add(dp1);
        mytb.Add(dp2);
        mytb.Add(dp3);
        mytb.Add(dp4);

        foreach (Departments dep  in mytb)
            {
                mytb2.Add(dep);
            }               
        
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;
       
    }     
    public static List<Departments> mytb { get; set; } = new List<Departments>();   

    public  ObservableCollection<Departments> mytb2 { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Departments>();     

    Departments dp1 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
    Departments dp2 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
    Departments dp3 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
    Departments dp4 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
```

it works fine . i am afraid to use the `foreach` loop as it might affect my application performance
so how to work this out ?

thx in advance

Comment: in your first example, you are creating an ObservableCollection from an empty list, so both will be empty.  Nowhere are you doing anything to add any data to `mytb`

Comment: Please post a [mcve], as @Jason says, your code examples doesn't show where/how/if you actually add items to any of the collections, and thus it is hard to reason about why it is behaving as you say it do.

Comment: secondly you don't have to loop through the data to add it to a ObservableCollection either.  You can initialize the mytb2 with its constructor passing in mytb... This all hinges on what @jason said that the list has data to begin with.

Comment: i alrdy have stuff in my `list<Departments> mytb` i just didnt want to write it down  to save some space, second tthing it works fine and show my stuff when i bind to `mytb` . but when i change my binding to `mytb2` nathing appears . so my question was why and is it okay to use the `foreeach `loop i will edit my question

Comment: again, you are creating `mytb2` before any data is added to `mytb`

Comment: yup that's true , you are right jason , thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netstandard-2.1) for your ObservableCollection mytb2. With default property, it would have not triggered the property changed notification to your UI.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  
  
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")  
{  
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

private ObservableCollection<Departments> _mytb2 = String.Empty;
public ObservableCollection<Departments> mytb2
{  
    get { return this._mytb2; }  
    set
    {
        if (value != this._mytb2)  
        {  
            this._mytb2 = value;  
            NotifyPropertyChanged();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another solution that worked as well
as jason said this is how i fixed this issue i just added this line of code

```
 mytb2  = new ObservableCollection<Departments>(mytb);
```

in here

```
 public MainPage()
{
    mytb.Add(dp1);
    mytb.Add(dp2);
    mytb.Add(dp3);
    mytb.Add(dp4);
    mytb2  = new ObservableCollection<Departments>(mytb);          
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = this;
   
}     
public static List<Departments> mytb { get; set; } = new List<Departments>();   

public ObservableCollection<Departments> mytb2 { get; set; }     

Departments dp1 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
Departments dp2 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
Departments dp3 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
Departments dp4 = new Departments() { FullName = "kkkkkk" };
```

Comment: if this is the correct answer, why did you accept the other answer?  That will just confuse future users who read this looking for help with a similar problem.